# Data arranging using awk command

Tags: awk, solaris

i have below data in a file name atp.txt:

```
Date_Time,Trx_ID,Message_ID,Status,Description,Amount,Trx_Type
2015-01-27 00:00:00 238,2057723456,BD9012700000003,200,Transaction Successful,1300,PRETOP
2015-01-27 00:00:00 253,2057724418,BD9012700000002,200,Transaction Successful,1600,PRETOP
2015-01-27 00:00:00 270,2057724430,BD9012700000001,200,Transaction Successful,2500,PRETOP
2015-01-27 00:00:00 430,2057724414,BD9012700000005,483,Customer next refill can be done after 10 minutes of successfull refill with same amount.,20150127000000425,
2015-01-27 00:00:00 523,2057723449,BD9012700000004,200,Transaction Successful,1500,POSTBILL
2015-01-27 00:00:04 858,2057724494,BD9012700000016,200,Transaction Successful,2000,PRETOP
2015-01-27 00:00:04 858,2057724485,BD9012700000015,200,Transaction Successful,1100,POSTBILL
```

i am using below command to arrange as per my requirement.

```
awk -F',' '{print $4","$7","$5}' atp.txt|sort -r|uniq -c
```

output is below:

```
1 Status,Trx_Type,Description
   8 515,,
  42 500,,Internal System Error.
   1 485,,Request recieved within a block time for Consecutive requests.
   4 484,,
2945 483,,Customer next refill can be done after 10 minutes of successfull refill with same amount.
 573 454,,Recharge not allowed for this subscriber.
  95 404,,Subscriber not found.
238527 200,PRETOP,Transaction Successful
 770 200,POSTBILL,Transaction Successful
  51 134,,Invalid PostPaid Bill payment amount.
```

but i want to show the count value at the later.
That is like below:

```
Status,Trx_Type,Description,1
200,POSTBILL,Transaction Successful,770
200,PRETOP,Transaction Successful,238527
515,,8,
454,,Recharge not allowed for this subscriber.,573
```

Please help me to modify the command.

Comment: What is the *count* value? Your csv names only name Date_Time,Trx_ID,Message_ID,Status,Description,Amount,Trx_Type.

Comment: Shouldn't the second to last output line be `515,,,8`?

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the output from `uniq -c` to another quick Awk or `sed` script to massage the output the way you like it.

```
... | uniq -c | sed '/^ *\([1-9][0-9]*\) *\(.*\)/\2,\1/'
```

Depending on the amount of data you have, you could also produce this from within your Awk script.  This will consume more memory within Awk, though.

```
awk -F',' '{++i[$4","$7","$5]}
    END {for (e in i) print e "," i[e] }' atp.txt | sort -r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the results one line at a time:

```
... | uniq -c | while read count rest; do
   echo "${rest},${count}"
done
```